# Getting a notification when my web service is down

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created a WCF SOAP web service in C# and a C# application. Other users will work with the application and are trying to get information from a local database via the web service.

Now is it possible that the web service can go down. Then I want as quickly as possible, let's say getting an email.

I can let the application which is by the users sending an email when they don't get a connection with the web service, but there are more than 10.000 users. And I don't want to get 500 emails when there are 500 online.

Is there a better solution for getting an email when my web service is down?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a sort of heartbeat program that runs on another server / location.

1. This will not only test the server, but also your internet connection for example;
2. Will work even when the power is down.

There are programs to do this already. The only I know is [Microsoft System Center](https://www.microsoft.com/sam/en/us/systemcenter.aspx) and [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of monitoring software packages out there if you want a pre-made tool. The company I work for uses New Relic. (http://newrelic.com/server-monitoring).

If you add a simple function to your webservice, that simply returns true, you can call it periodically (maybe every minute?). If it times out, your service is down, and your monitoring program can email you.